# Is it possible to omit "電話を'

Tags: grammar

In the sentence like:

> ホテルに電話をかけます

Can we omit "電話を" and say:

> ホテルにかけます

The logic here goes this way: "かけ" means "to make call" so, the "電話を" should be implied. Is it correct?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: かける by itself does not mean "to make a call". かける is one of the Japanese [light verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42912/8629).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

かける has some meanings, so you should not omit 電話を. However if it means obviously "電話をかける", you can omit it.

For example,

A:ホテルに予約の電話をかけてもいいかな?

B:いいよ、かけて。